# How to make MUI outlined Textfield label RTL?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, textfield, right-to-left, theming

I use MUI v4 and I have an RTL theme (I put `direction: 'rtl'` inside the theme), and it works fine until I use an outlined `TextField` - for some reason the value itself is aligned RTL but the label is attached the `top left` position of the `TextField`.

How can I change that to be fully RTL?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use custom style

The text field uses the **transform-origin** and **left** properties to align the label by default.

If you are using styled-component you can use this code:

```
export const custom TextField = styled(TextField)({
'& label': {
    transformOrigin: "right !important",
    left: "inherit !important",
    right: "1.75rem !important",
    fontSize: "small",
    color: "#807D7B",
    fontWeight: 400,
    overflow: "unset",
},
```

});

Or rewrite it using class TextField like this :

```
.css-1kty9di-MuiFormLabel-root-MuiInputLabel-root{
left: inherit !important;
right: 1.75rem !important;
transform-origin: right !important;
```

}

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you very much!

Comment: The gap in the top border needs to go to the right too.
```"& legend": {  textAlign: "right", },```